# How to make changes to XAML during runtime/debugging and show changes without a restart?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

When running my application it is fairly slow to load. So in order to speed up development I am wanting to run my views independently using a testing framework (to avoid needing the whole application load up).

In the process of doing this, I have found that when my views are run from the test runner. I am unable to make changes in XAML and have them reflect in the running application. For example; If I add a textbox to the view via XAML while running, it will not show. I have to restart the test to make it show.

However, when I run my application as a whole. I can edit the XAML and have it make changes to the running app. That is adding a textbox to the view via XAML during running DOES show.

At first I thought it was because the tests were in a different project. So I moved it into the main assembly (everything is in the one assembly/project). The problem is still there. So there must be something else.

One difference, is that I am running my tests from a base class, although I am not sure that should make a difference.

Can anyone tell me how to ensure I can make changes without needing to restart the test?

Comment: name of that testing framework ?

Comment: Sorry. It is the microsoft testing framework. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework